# Multithreading with recursively created worker threads, await all before continuing

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-core

I've got a program that recursively reads files for references to parse specific data. Right now I'm just doing it plain and simple in a single thread, but would like to use something like worker threads for every new file read to improve the speed of the application. Is this a realistic plan? I haven't really worked with proper multithreading before and wouldn't know how I would then await the completion of all file parses before continuing with the program. The resulting data from all the file parses gets stored in a main `Hashset`, order etc doesn't matter so I shouldn't need to worry about the thread safety of that collection, I think. I do however need all the data before the program continues.

Any hints in the right direction would be appreciated!

EDIT:
I am probably wrong with my assumption on the thread safety of the collection.

Also, the recursive file parse roughly works as follows: I have a root file which can reference a set of different asset files, which then again could in their own way reference more assets. This could, for example, be:

- a Model file referencing a Material referencing a Texture
- a Map referencing a Particle referencing a Texture
- a Map referencing another Map as a prefab, which again references other stuff etc etc

This branching, especially regarding map prefabs, is what I currently think is a big bottleneck for speed with bigger root files and more complex reference trees.
I need all of those unique source file references, which is what I am storing them in a `Hashset` for.

Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: First, work out if your current work is *I/O* bound (spending time waiting for files to be read) or *CPU* bound. There's no point in adding threads and more stress to I/O if that's the bottleneck.

Comment: "so I shouldn't need to worry about the thread safety of that collection" That sure doesn't sound true at all.  It's a statement that's almost never true when you have multiple threads accessing a collection, and I see no reason why this would be an exception.

Comment: If order doesn't matter, I'd actually question the "recursive" approach. I am pretty confident you'll get more satisfying results by using a queue which you can have handled by several workers.

Comment: Re, "order etc doesn't matter so I shouldn't need to worry about the thread safety of that collection;"  Thread safety isn't about doing things in correct order. If you need things done in a certain order, then you should do all of the things in one thread. Thread safety is about maintaining integrity/validity/correctness of shared data structures. If your `Hashset` is not "thread-safe" then concurrent operations on it from different threads could corrupt the data and/or crash your program.

Comment: Q: Out of curiosity, When you say, "recursively reads files," are you talking about a [_recursive descent parser_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser)? or are you talking about something else? What is "recursive" about the way in which you read the files?

Comment: Are you reading the files form a SSD, or from a classic hard disk?

Comment: Is the program reading the full files or just file information (name, size, last access, etc.) ?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever How could I benchmark this easily?

Comment: @SolomonSlow You're probably right on thread safety, then. As I mentioned, I've never done much in terms of multithreading

Comment: Also regarding the recursive parse. The files I am reading are asset files that can reference different types of other asset files, some of which can then reference more assets etc. What my program does is basically collect all unique references via the hashset

Comment: updated post with the details, sorry for the lack of info in the original post!

Comment: It's generally not beneficial to run more threads than you have CPU cores. And as Damien pointed out, it's generally not beneficial to spawn threads for I/O-bound tasks. Rule of thumb, you should explicitly spawn threads for CPU-bound tasks, and use the managed thread pool with async/await for I/O-bound tasks.